# RTK Query - Default Cache Behavior not clearing

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, rtk-query

I have a functional component(modal) that uses a custom hook that uses a lazy query. I confirmed the component unmounts via a useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log('modal unmount')
    }
  }, [])
```

However after 60 seconds, the query result remains in Redux despite what the documentation states:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/cache-behavior

> As long as there is an active 'subscription' to the data (e.g. if a
> component is mounted that calls a useQuery hook for the endpoint),
> then the data will remain in the cache. Once the subscription is
> removed (e.g. when last component subscribed to the data unmounts),
> after an amount of time (default 60 seconds), the data will be removed
> from the cache.

So the implementation is route-->landing component-->modal-->custom hook-->RTK query and the cache entry never goes away after I close the modal, see the unmount and wait 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason for that would be that you did not include `api.middleware` in the store setup.

You **should** have warnings about that in your console.

Another reason could be that you still have other components subscribed to that slice - you can see the subscribers in the RTK Query devtools.

Comment: Thanks! The middleware wasn't added to the configureStore.